# How to fit an implicit equation to a data set, with one fitting parameter: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve

I am trying to fit an implicit equation to a set of data extracted from a paper as shown below.

[image: image from paper]

The data set contains particle concentration, `phi`, across a gap of radius, `R`. The data for `phi` and `R` are given below.

```
phi(Ri) = phi(1);
Ri = R(1);
n = 2;
phiM = 0.68
Kc / Ku = fitting parameters.
R = [4.47 4.59 4.69 4.81 4.92 5.02 5.13 5.24 5.35 5.46 5.57 5.68];
phi = [0.569 0.570 0.573 0.576 0.578 0.581 0.585 0.589 0.593 0.595 0.598 0.602];
```

I am trying to fit the equation 16 to the data set provided. I am at a complete loss as to how to fit an equation to a set of data where phi is on both sides of the equation. I have fitted data to equation before. However it was always explicit (`y = f(x)`) .

Every time I try to type the fitting equation into the curve fitting toolbox, I am warned that I can not have `y` on both sides of the equation. What do I do for these types of equation where the curve fitting tool cannot be used?

Any help or guidance towards how I can learn move about these sort of fitting will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the function `fminsearch`. This function can be used together with the `norm(yc-yr)` where yc are the calculated y values from the function and yr are the values you want to fit to. Then you will basically perform a non-linear least squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by defining your known variables, as given in your question:

```
% Known parameters
R = [4.47 4.59 4.69 4.81 4.92 5.02 5.13 5.24 5.35 5.46 5.57 5.68];
phi = [0.569 0.570 0.573 0.576 0.578 0.581 0.585 0.589 0.593 0.595 0.598 0.602];
phi_Ri = phi(1);  Ri = R(1);
n = 2;            phiM = 0.68;
```

Now define your function, but subtract the left hand side so that we can put the equation equal to zero. This function will be in terms of the `x` parameter (`R`), the `y` parameter (`phi`) and the only unknown, `kk` which is defined as Ku/Kc in (16).

```
F = @(x,y,kk) ((x/Ri).^2).*((1-phi_Ri/phiM)./(1-y/phiM)).^(n*(1-kk)) - (y/phi_Ri);
```

Now we can use `fminsearch`, with some initial guess for `kk`, to find the "best" value. You can define "best" however you like, in this case I've taken the norm of `F`, meaning the *distance* between the calculated `x` and `y` coordinates and the given values for `R` and `phi`. Because the function `F` should be equal to 0, minimising it makes sense!

```
% Min search based on norm, with initial guess KuKcMin = 1
KuKcMin = fminsearch(@(KuKc) norm(F(R,phi,KuKc)), 1);
```

In this example, `KuKcMin = 1.6735` so Kc/Ku = 1/1.6735 = 0.5975 which is similar to right-hand figure in paper.

Now we have to use `ezplot` to plot the implicit function, we'll also plot the original points.

```
ezplot(@(x,y)F(x,y,KuKcMin), [4.2,6,0.56,0.61]); % 4-element array is axes limits
hold on;
plot(R,phi,'o');
xlabel('R'); ylabel('\phi'); title('');
```

Output:

[image: output]

You can verify that the plotting and function `F` are working correctly by changing the parameters `n`, `phiM` and `KuKcMin` to reproduce the plots in the paper above:

[image: output 2]

---

**Edit:**

The axes range passed as an input to `ezplot` is the entire plotting range, not just what is *visible*. Your new data doesn't lie within the old limits, so we must adapt!

```
phi = [0.285 0.285 0.293 0.298 0.299 0.303 0.309 0.310 0.310 0.312 0.315 0.317 0.318 0.318 0.321 0.321 0.321 0.324 0.327 0.325 0.326 0.332 0.335 0.333 0.336];
R = [4.190 4.365 4.540 4.714 4.889 5.063 5.238 5.413 5.587 5.762 5.937 6.111 6.286 6.460 6.635 6.810 6.984 7.159 7.333 7.508 7.683 7.857 8.032 8.206 8.381];
phi_Ri = phi(1);  Ri = R(1);  n = 2;  phiM = 0.68;
F = @(x,y,kk) ((x/Ri).^2).*((1-phi_Ri/phiM)./(1-y/phiM)).^(n*(1-kk)) - (y/phi_Ri);
KuKcMin = fminsearch(@(KuKc) norm(F(R,phi,KuKc)), 1);
% NOTE: change the ezplot    <-- axes limits -->
ezplot(@(x,y)F(x,y,KuKcMin), [4.18,8.4,0.28,0.34]); % 4-element array is axes limits
hold on; plot(R,phi,'o'); xlabel('R'); ylabel('\phi'); title('');
```

To make your code more generic, you could always use `ezplot` over the same range as your data. You may want to add some padding or rounding.

```
ezplot(@(x,y)F(x,y,KuKcMin), [min(R),max(R),min(phi),max(phi)]);
```

Output:

[image: output 3]

Comment: Hi Wolfie, many thanks for all your help. 

It took me a while to figure out how to change the value of Ku/Kc, however everything looks really good now. 

I was just wondering do you have any idea why the function seems to limit plotting at around x=6.23? 

I only ask because I have tried fitting a set of data from another paper where the "r" is larger. However the data fitting seems to cut off at 6.23.

You have helped me massively and I just want to thank you.

Comment: I completely forgot to add the data that I am working with now. If you can have a quick look that will be really appreciated. 

R = [4.190 4.365 4.540 4.714 4.889 5.063 5.238 5.413 5.587 5.762 5.937 6.111 6.286 6.460 6.635 6.810 6.984 7.159 7.333 7.508 7.683 7.857 8.032 8.206 8.381];
phi = [ 0.285 0.285 0.293 0.298 0.299 0.303 0.309 0.310 0.310 0.312 0.315 0.317 0.318 0.318 0.321 0.321 0.321 0.324 0.327 0.325 0.326 0.332 0.335 0.333 0.336];

Comment: Hi Wolfie, many thanks. I thought that might be issue too and tried removing the limits. It looks like I just had to extend the limit. Many thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, if you see the [documentation for `ezplot`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html) then the default limits are `-2π < x < 2π, -2π < y < 2π`, hence your plot stopping at "just over 6.23" which is approx. 2π was the expected behaviour! :)